# Using Regex to count the number of times that I have both a name and its proportion

Tags: r, regex

I have the following dataset and I wish to count how many times I have both "Adam" and "Adam David"

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), names = c( "Adam, David, Adam David", 
"Adam David, Maddy Kones, Adam David"))
```

so my ideal out put is

```
id                              names  count 
1               Adam, David, Adam David  1
2   Adam David, Maddy Kones, Adam David  0
```

Is there anyway? I tried to use `str_count` in `stringr` package like that

```
library(stringr)
df$count <- str_count(df$names, c("Adam David", "Adam"))
```

Ans some other Regex but I was unsuccessful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could split by `,`, then get the count

```
df$count <- as.integer(sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$names), ",\\s*"),
                 function(x) all(c("Adam", "Adam David") %in% x)))
```

---

Or using `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
+(Reduce(`&`, lapply(c("Adam\\s*,", "Adam David"), function(x) str_count(df$names, x)>0)))
```